# The condition for mutually orthogonal Latin square

Tags: co.combinatorics, latin-square

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are Latin squares of order $n$. And suppose any column of $A$ and any column of $B$ have common entry only once. Then are $A$ and $B$ mutually orthogonal?

I know the converse is true, but I don't know whether this is true, and how to prove this.

Comment: What do you mean by the converse and by mutual orthogonality? There is an example on Wikipedia of mutually orthogonal Latin squares of order 3, and the first columns are identical: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_orthogonal_Latin_squares

Comment: I forgot to mention this. They are Mutually orthogonal latin squares of order n and their first row is fixed by (1,2,...,n). Then I think converse is true.

Comment: Do you also require the fixed first row property for the original question?

Comment: Yes. A and B should have same first row. (Both original question and converse)

Comment: Please edit the clarification into the original question (it makes it more visible, and save readers the time of having to go through the comments).